# What is the best way to send a string of values using AJAX in a Ruby on Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm getting values from the html using the following method:

javascript:

```
var list = "1,2,3,4";
$.post($(this).attr("action"), "my_list=" + list, null, "script");
```

html:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", :id => "save_bottom" %>
```

In my controller params[:my_list] has the value "1,2,3,4".  I can then iterate through it to get the values.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? Are there specific ruby functions that I should use?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "/widgets",
        data: { list : [1,2,3,4] },
        success: function(htmlText){
          jQuery('#widgets').html(htmlText);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
      });
```

now in your controller:

```
    params[:list]
```

Comment: How do I convert the list variable string "1,2,3,4" to a [1,2,3,4] that you are sending via the jQuery.ajax function?